# How to represent an image as state in a Q-table

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to do Q-learning with the Atari games using the `gym` python's package.

I want to use the image as the state of my algorithm, but I came up with a doubt: **Is the state all the possibilities for all the pixels of the image?**

I've seen many Q-learning implementations, and in the Q-table they always store all the possible states as rows, and the actions as columns (for example, https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/reinforcement-q-learning-scratch-python-openai-gym/)

Without doing maths, all the possible states for, let's say, a 200x200 grayscale image are insane. How can I handle this problem without doing neural networks?

I guess there must be an approach for this scenario, but I haven't found any good example.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atari games are some of the best examples in which you would need a function approximator (e.g. Neural Network) in order to solve them. This is because the state space explodes and thus you would need something that will generalize quite well in unseen states.

I am not quite sure what you mean by

> I want to use the image as the state of my algorithm, but I came up with a doubt: Is the state all the possibilities for all the pixels of the image?

The state at a specific timestep represents the state of the game and will be the input to your algorithm. Why you would need all the possible combinations of the pixels in that image (most of these combinations won't make any sense and the agent will never encounter them. What you need though is your agent to encounter enough **game states** that will enable it to generalize well in unseen states.

If you were trying to solve Atari games with a look up table then you would have to store every single image, that your agent encounters at every single time step, in a table (more precisely a reference of that image which will correspond to a $Q$ value). In other words you are trying to store all the states that your agent might encounter in the game (impossible in Atari games - unless you do some very sloppy assumptions about the nature of the states).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The professor made a mistake and now he added to the statement we should use CNNs or use a smaller environment (basically another game like the Frozen Lake). Thaat's why I was very confused about how to solve the problem without NNs.